# Ioslide appearing black

Tags: r, ioslides

This is a general question. If you run a current chunk (green arrow to the right) and it produces the desired result but yet it does not knit, what causes that? When I knit, the sixth slide in this case turns black but yet when you run current chunk or run selected lines, it works. Any insights would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the event that your ioslide runs (run current chunk or run selected lines) but yet turns black, it is as simple as needing to have the title of the slide be " ##" and not "##".